# iPhone audio frameworks

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, audiotoolbox

Does AVFoundation Framework internally speak to AudioToolbox Framework? Because AudioToolbox holds all these services

1. Audio Converter Services
2. Audio File Services
3. Audio File Stream Services
4. Audio Format Services
5. Audio Queue Services
6. Audio Session Services
7. Audio Unit Processing Graph Services
8. Extended Audio File Services
9. System Sound Services

If incase , AVFoundation framework wants to convert audio file, how does it do?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but just had quite the same, so I just asked our old friend `otool`, *`-L print shared libraries used`*:

```
otool -L /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation (architecture armv6):
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 751.49.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 296.0.0)
    (more ...)
```

So the answer is **yes, AVFoundation talks to AudioToolbox**.

To get more details on a specific method implementation would require further analysis involving some more reverse engineering ...